# Why is this delegate syntax "legal"?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, anonymous-methods

I am reading about anonymous methods and am trying to wrap my head around this example:

`List<int> evenNumbers = list.FindAll(delegate(int i)

{ return (i % 2) == 0; } )`

Why is `delegate(int i)` legal? You aren't having to declare `new delegate void` or anything like that.

Is that what is meant by anonymous method? Is this the added syntactic sugar that allows for anonymous methods?

Comment: Since you started to learn anonymous methods, you should take a look at `lambda expressions` if you didn't already. I think you might find them interesting.

Comment: @Poma: Thanks! I'm on to that next!  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's legal because of what you suspect, it's creating an anonymous delegate/method.

An alternative (using the [lambda operator =>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx)) would be:

```
List<int> evenNumbers = list.FindAll((i) => ((i % 2) == 0));
```

or

```
List<int> evenNumbers = list.FindAll(i => i % 2 == 0);
```

See [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) for further reading.

Comment: Or the same thing without the 6 extra parentheses. :-) +1

Comment: You can clean it up by removing all your parentheses: `var evenNumbers = list.FindAll(i => i % 2 == 0);`

Comment: I kept them in so you could more easily see the direct translation.

Answer (score 1):

If you decompose the statement a little, hopefully it will be more obvious - this is the equivalent code.

```
Predicate<int> test = delegate(int i)
{
    return (i % 2) == 0;
};

List<int> evenNumbers = list.FindAll(test);
```

As you can see it created an anonymous delegate (that the compiler will turn into a method behind the scenes)

Personally I've always found the "inline" anonymous delegate syntax to cloud the issue more than add clarity whereas the same construct built using a lambda expression, once you are used to the syntax, adds clarity

```
List<int> evenNumbers = list.FindAll(i => i % 2 == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

in this code it seems like passing a method into a method using a delegate.